# laravel model relationships and multi level roles

Tags: php, laravel

i've Admin model & Role model. the Admin model has multiple roles. i want to check if `admin == role_a` then do `what role_a is assigned for`, if `admin == role_b` then do `what role_b is assigned for`. how can i do it ? and how to fetch a single data from a model, such as roles from Role model to check the logged in role == which type of admin or vice-versa.

here is `Admin.php` model ->

```
class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'admin';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }
}
```

here is `Role.php` model ->

```
class Role extends Model
{
    public function admins()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Admin');
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're trying to deploy Role and permission for your application!
In this case, i would recommend to take a look at `spatie\laravel-permission`
https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/laravel-permission

Answer (score 0):

you Can make a table permissions with Model Permission 
and make a Relation with Role Model

```
class Role extends Model {
  //your code

  public function permissions(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission');
  }
}
```

then you can use admin controller to get admin with permissions

```
class AdminController extends Controller{
  public function show($id){
    $admin = App\Admin::with(['role.permissions])->find($id);
    dd($admin->role()->permissions);
    }
}
```

or you can use a package of roles like [laratrust](https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/) or [spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) or[entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust)